# How to use v-bind in a custom component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

According to the doc,

`<input v-model="something">` is the same as:

```
<input
 v-bind:value="something"
 v-on:input="something = $event.target.value">
```

so I tried following and it works:

```
<input v-model='sample'>
<input v-bind:value='sample' v-on:input="sample = $event.target.value" >
```

now when I tried the same in a custom component, it triggers an error:

> VM99:2Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7gjkbhy3/15/)

What am I missing here to make it work ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are emitting an `input` event inside an `input` event handler.

So the problem that happens here is:

1. First `input` when you type in the `<input>`

   ```
   input: function(event) {
     self.$emit("input", event.target.value) // 2
   }
   ```

   You emit the value input to the target element.
2. Second emit is caused by the handler itself,

   ```
   input: function(event) {
     /* the value of event is no longer a DOM el
      instead it is a string value which doesn't have a target property 
      it throws an error on the console. */

     self.$emit("input", event.target.value)
   }
   ```

   > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4wLcgfr/1/).

**EDIT**

Also, in your component HTML, you are expecting `$event` to have a `target` which further should have a `value` property.

```
self.$emit("input", event.target.value)
```

Here you are emitting a value therefore, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks, the v-bind works, but the v-model does not in the fiddle

Comment: @AngeloC Please check the updated fiddle, in your template too you were expecting `$event.target.value`.

Comment: that fiddle works, thanks. but I was just wondering why 'myinput' can not work the same way as 'input'

Comment: @AngeloC An input emits `$event.target.value` natively, you are emitting a string value in your handler, not just that, in your case it happens twice. First time when you start typing and then you emit the value again through an `input` event. In the `<input>` tag it happens just each time you type, there is no second `$emit` happening. Which maintains the expected value of `$event.target.value`.

Answer (score 10):

I get the same problem following the documentation :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

**You can get the value directly by `$event` instead of `$event.target.value`**

---

This is the example of documentation with **working code** :

```
Vue.component('custom-input', {
  props: ['value'],
  template: `
    <input
      :value="value"
      @input="$emit('input', $event)"
    >
  `
})
```

Now `v-model` should work perfectly with this component:

```
<custom-input v-model="searchText"></custom-input>
```